# Derivation of deformation formula in physics textbook

Tags: derivatives

There is a derivation of a deformation formula for rocks in one of my textbooks which I don't quite follow.  As the problem is mathematical, I've decided to post it here The derivation goes as follows:

> Denote the internal energy per unit volume of rock as $u(\epsilon_{ij},v,s)$ and the free energy as $f(\epsilon_{ij}, p, T) = u - Ts - pv$.  For isothermal deformations, infinitesimal variations $d\epsilon_{ij}$ and $dp$ result in a variation $df$:
>
> $$df = \sigma_{ij} d\epsilon_{ij} - vdp$$
>
> Because $df$ is a total differential one finds:
>
> $$\left( \frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial p} \right)_{\epsilon_{ij}} = - \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial \epsilon_{ij}} \right)_p$$

I follow everything until the last step.  I know the definition of a differential, but I am a bit confused since the last expression contains partial differentials of $\sigma$ and $v$.  If someone can illustrate to me how we get from the $df = \sigma_{ij} d\epsilon_{ij} - vdp$ to the final expression, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the total differential $df$ may be written from calculus as

$$df=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_{ij}}\right)_p d\epsilon_{ij}
+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}\right)_{\epsilon_{ij}} dp$$
From this we identify $\sigma_{ij}=\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_{ij}}\right)_p$ and $v=-\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial p}\right)_{\epsilon_{ij}}.$ Assuming the symmetry of second derivatives (i.e. Schwarz's theorem) we conclude that

$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial p \partial\,\epsilon_{ij}}
=\left(\frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial p}\right)_{\epsilon_{ij}}
=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \epsilon_{ij}\,\partial p }
=-\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \epsilon_{ij}}\right)_{p}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This explains it beautifully!

Comment: Note that you'll see this trick a bunch in thermodynamics contexts: It's an example of a Maxwell relation.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll keep this in mind from now on :)

Answer (score 2):

This comes from [Schwartz Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives).

Indeed, from the expression $ df  = \sigma_{ij} d \epsilon_{ij} - \nu dp $, you have

$$ \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon_{ij}} \right)_{p} = \sigma_{ij}
\\
\displaystyle \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \right)_{\epsilon_{ij}} = - \nu
\end{cases}
$$

Schwartz Theorem gives you that

$$ \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial p \partial \epsilon_{ij}} = \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial \epsilon_{ij} \partial p} \, ,$$

from which you immediately obtain the desired expression $\displaystyle \left( \frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial p} \right)_{\epsilon_{ij}} = - \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial \epsilon_{ij}} \right)_{p}$

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Really appreciate it :)